# How to integrate Vue.js with Django

Tags: django, vue.js

I have a classic Django (no SPA) web project. Django renders also my templates. 
I wanted to implement Vue.js for some frontend functionalities (actually a search field) in the project. 
There is already a basic working version with separated files under my assets directory: 

`assets/
  css/
    search.css
  js/
    search.js`

How can I write a structure using separate `.vue` components for my project? 
Should I use webpack + [django-webpack-loader](https://github.com/ezhome/django-webpack-loader)? Is there a more simple way?

Comment: I think it is safe to say that all structures are **"component-oriented"**. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Do you want to keep Django in charge of managing the template files? Or do you want to use VueJS to build a single-page application? If you only want to use it for a search box, you can simply include VueJS with the `<script>` element. This way you can add a small component to your page, similar to how you'd use jQuery. Then you'd need to use `axios`, the Fetch API or a package of your choice to make requests to an API.

If you want to use Vue components and leave Django in charge of templates, have a look at this: https://github.com/NdagiStanley/vue-django

Comment: My question is about a minimal .vue files based integration in my Django project. It is not a SPA. The concepts about django-ajax-vuejs workaround are already clear for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've no Django experience, but ;-) the simplest way of integrating Vue is to create your vue components in .js files, not .vue files. As soon as you put your Vue stuff in .vue files, you need bundling, so you're talking SPA. Define your components in .js files. Use template strings (backticks) for the template property.  The only thing you lose, relative to .vue files, is component-scoped css. You need to be a little bit careful that Vue doesn't break existing DOM manipulation code, but this is a perfectly workable way to start out.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you already know this, but to give a better context, it is worth specifying the three traditional ways of working with VueJS in general:

1. Integrated directly into HTML using a script tag (very effective if
   what you want is just to implement small features and avoiding the
   use of jQuery).
2. Doing it inside a JS file, as @bbsimonbb mentions
   (but I don't recommend it, the project quickly becomes
   unmaintainable and increases the difficulty of working with HTML).
3. Working on .vue files and moving towards a SPA.

In the case of Django there is an alternative that takes place halfway between the first and third option, using the [django-webpack-loader](https://github.com/owais/django-webpack-loader) package. Following the tutorial in the repository is quite simple to implement the functionality, and in the process avoid CORS management.